# codeigniter foreach datatables

Tags: codeigniter, datatable, foreach

tengo una consulta

```
  $this->datatables
            ->select(....)
```

después de lo cual necesito realizar un recorrido a los registros intento

```
$results = $this->datatables->generate();

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo $row;
        exit();
    }
```

pero a la hora de imprimir row no me regresa nada, de igual manera tengo que cambiar un valor directo en la variable sin impactar la base de datos, alguna idea??

de igual manera me ayudaría algo de documentación al respecto algún tutorial que me recomienden?

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente $row esté definido como un objeto. Para poder imprimir o modificar un valor determinado, deberías indicar también el nombre del campo, por ejemplo:

```
$this->datatables->select('field1, field2');

$results = $this->datatables->generate();

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row->field1;
    echo $row->field2;
    exit();
}
```

La otra opción, creo que menos probable, es que venga devuelto como un array:

```
$this->datatables->select('field1, field2');

$results = $this->datatables->generate();

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row['field1'];
    echo $row['field2'];
    exit();
}
```

En cualquier caso, puedes imprimir un var_dump() de la variable $results para ver qué devuelve exactamente la funcion generate() de datatables.